# Como crear un trigger que me replique los datos en otra tabla con campos parecidos

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Tengo la siguiente tabla ChekInOut

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual se inserta los datos ejecutandose un procedimiento almacenado guardado a continuación hago un insert a la tabla y efectivamente me registra.

```
INSERT INTO CheckInOut (UserDeviceId, DispositivoId, CIOTDeviceId, FechaCompleta, Fecha, TiempoCompleto, HoraMinuto, TiempoMinutos, Hora, Minuto, Segundo, status, InsertDate)
VALUES ('706855','6','1','2020-03-30 17:35:10','2020-03-30','15:35:10','17:35','350','17','35','00',1,GETDATE())
```

--Ahora quiero hacer una trigger para que cuando inserte información en la tabla ChekInOut me replique los datos de las columnas (UserDeviceId,FechaCompleta,) a la tabla ChekInOut3 está es la estructura de la tabla, cabe señalar que (UserDeviceId =NU_DOCU_IDEN y FechaCompleta=FE_REGI_RELO) en la otra tabla ChekInOut3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el trigger que yo hice

```
create trigger replicaCheckInOut
on CheckInOut
after insert
as
insert into CheckInOut3 (NU_DOCU_IDEN,CO_EMPR,ID_REGI,FE_REGI_RELO,TI_DOCU,NU_HRAS,CO_CENT_COST,CO_ORDE_SERV,CO_RELO,DE_OBSE,ST_TRAN,DE_OBSE_LOGS,CO_USUA_CREA,FE_USUA_CREA)
select right ('000000' + UserDeviceId,8),DispositivoId,CIOTDeviceId,FechaCompleta,Fecha,'','','','','','','',status,InsertDate
from inserted
```

PERO CUANDO HAGO EL INSERT PARA INGRESAR NUEVA DATA Y QUE SE REPLIQUE EN LA OTRA TABLA ME SALE ESTE MENSAJE:

> Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Procedure replicaCheckInOut, Line 28
>   Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
>   'CheckInOut3' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está ocurriendo es que tienes un campo en la tabla `CheckInOut3` con un autonumérico (`identity`) y no te deja insertar datos en ese campo. Desconozco cuál debe ser pero apostaría a que es el campo `ID_REGI`.

Puedes hacer tres cosas:

1) Eliminar la opción de identidad de este campo.

2) No insertar el valor en este campo y que tome el valor autonumérico de forma habitual.

3) Desactivar temporalmente esta característica, para que te permita
    insertar el valor de la otra tabla, para ello debes hacer un 
`SET IDENTITY_INSERT CheckInOut3 ON;`:

```
create trigger replicaCheckInOut
on CheckInOut
after insert
as

SET IDENTITY_INSERT CheckInOut3 ON; 

insert into CheckInOut3 (NU_DOCU_IDEN,CO_EMPR,ID_REGI,FE_REGI_RELO,TI_DOCU,NU_HRAS,CO_CENT_COST,CO_ORDE_SERV,CO_RELO,DE_OBSE,ST_TRAN,DE_OBSE_LOGS,CO_USUA_CREA,FE_USUA_CREA)
select right ('000000' + UserDeviceId,8),DispositivoId,CIOTDeviceId,FechaCompleta,Fecha,'','','','','','','',status,InsertDate
from inserted

SET IDENTITY_INSERT CheckInOut3 OFF;
```

Comment: funciono con lo ultimo estimado muchas gracias otra consulta, en caso quiera hacer lo mismo pero en otra base de datos, en que cambiaría el trigger.

Comment: Si las tablas y campos se llaman igual, no cambia nada

Comment: los campos son iguales pero la tabla se llama distinta, esta en ota base de datos y en otra instancia tambien.

Comment: Pues simplemente le cambias el nombre en el trigger de `CheckInOut` y de  `CheckInOut3` por el nombre que tengan en la otra base de datos y ya está

Answer (score 0):

No encuentro mucho sentido a poner una clave primaria compuesta en CheckInOut3 formada por ID_REGUI y Fe_regi_relo, mas aún cuando la vas a utilizar con la fecha del sistema.
Si generas un identity este ya identifica al registro, por tanto además de no ser necesario, te penalizará.

No obstante el problema del triger es que estas mencionando la clave identity. Id_Regui en la insercción. Y esto no se pone en la sentencia insert.

Yo cambiaría la definición de la tabla, y es más incluso aplicaría una default a la columna Fe_regi_Relo, para que me insertase por defecto la fecha del sistema.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CheckInOut
create table CheckInOut 
( userDeviceID varchar(100) null
, DispositivoId int not null
, CIOTDeviceId INT NULL
, CheckInOutWorkCode int
, CheckInOutId int  identity(1,1) Primary key
, FechaCompleta datetime not null
, Fecha datetime
, TiempoCompleto char(8)
, HoraMinuto char(5)
, TiempoMinutos int
, Hora char(2)
, Minuto char(2)
, Segundo char(2)
, status int
, InsertDate datetime
, Updatedate datetime
, userUpdate int null)
go
SET DATEFORMAT MDY
INSERT INTO CheckInOut (UserDeviceId, DispositivoId, CIOTDeviceId, FechaCompleta, Fecha, TiempoCompleto, HoraMinuto, TiempoMinutos,
Hora, Minuto, Segundo, status, InsertDate)
VALUES ('706855','6','1','2020-03-30 17:35:10','2020-03-30','15:35:10','17:35','350','17','35','00',1,GETDATE())
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CheckInOut3
CREATE TABLE CHECKINOUT3 
(ID_REGI INT IDENTITY(1,1)
, TI_DOCU VARCHAR(3)
, NU_DOCU_IDEN VARCHAR(20)
, FE_rEGI_RELO DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())
, PRIMARY KEY (ID_REGI, FE_REGI_RELO)
)
GO

CREATE trigger replicaCheckInOut
on CheckInOut
after insert
as
insert into CheckInOut3 (NU_DOCU_IDEN,TI_DOCU)
select right ('000000' + UserDeviceId,8),DispositivoId
from inserted
GO
INSERT INTO CheckInOut (UserDeviceId, DispositivoId, CIOTDeviceId, FechaCompleta, Fecha, TiempoCompleto, HoraMinuto, TiempoMinutos, Hora, Minuto, Segundo, status, InsertDate)
VALUES ('706855','6','1','2020-03-30 17:35:10','2020-03-30','15:35:10','17:35','350','17','35','00',1,GETDATE())
```

Es tu mismo ejemplo. En la tabla checkInOut3 no he replicado todas las columnas porque no aportan nada al ejemplo.

Por otro lado el trigger, además de ser simple, es completamente correcto. No inserta una linea, inserta todas las que le vengan.

```
INSERT INTO CheckInOut (UserDeviceId, DispositivoId, CIOTDeviceId, FechaCompleta, Fecha, TiempoCompleto, HoraMinuto, TiempoMinutos, Hora, Minuto, Segundo, status, InsertDate)
VALUES 
('706855','6','1','2020-03-30 17:35:10','2020-03-30','15:35:10','17:35','350','17','35','00',1,GETDATE()),
('706855','6','1','2020-03-30 17:35:10','2020-03-30','15:35:10','17:35','350','17','35','00',1,GETDATE()),
('706855','6','1','2020-03-30 17:35:10','2020-03-30','15:35:10','17:35','350','17','35','00',1,GETDATE()),
('706855','6','1','2020-03-30 17:35:10','2020-03-30','15:35:10','17:35','350','17','35','00',1,GETDATE()),
('706855','6','1','2020-03-30 17:35:10','2020-03-30','15:35:10','17:35','350','17','35','00',1,GETDATE());
```

> (5 filas afectadas)
>
> (5 filas afectadas)
>
> Hora de finalización: 2020-04-07T18:10:03.6074937+02:00

Answer (score -1):

SELECT TOP 1 recuerda que los triggers trabajan de 1 en 1 no en select multiple

Comment: Los triggers en Sql Server, utilizan la pseudo-tabla `inserted`, y **no van fila por fila**. Todas las filas que vengan en la inserción, estarán en este conjunto y por tanto puedes aplicar lógica de conjuntos al mismo.

Answer (score -1):

Debes usar SET IDENTITY INSERT y apagarlo al final

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_bien_ins
ON tabla_que_dispara
AFTER  INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tabla_donde_se_insertara ON
    INSERT INTO 
    tabla_donde_se_insertara(
    id,
    datos
    )
SELECT
 id,
 datos
    
FROM
    inserted --nombre que recibe automáticamente la tabla temporal del sql 
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tabla_donde_se_insertara OFF

END
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [answer].

Comment: y que es SET IDENTITY INSERT ? ... esto es una respuesta a medias ...